# Add Close button in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview which is shown in the partial screen area. I want to make it closeable by adding a top right corner close button. Currently the listview looks like:

[image]

I want to make it look like:

[image]

I thought of adding the listview inside a Dialog but then having similar close button in dialog is also not straight way. Any API or work around to make the ListView closeable?

Comment: What do you mean by close? `setAdapter(null);` ?? Why you don't just add a button which has `android:layout_above` with anchor the listview and align parent right ? And your listview has `android:height = wrap_content` ?? Should work...

Comment: What about adding a button abouve your list and in his ClickListener set ListView Visibility to GONE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a button on top of the listView in your xml file.

For the button, set up the .setOnClickListener. Inside onClick, you can use listViewname.setVisibility(viewname.INVISIBLE). That will hide the listview for all practical purposes.

If that doesn't work for you, you can also use an expandableListView. In the group of ExpandableListView, have a X button and display all the rows as child. If you click on the cross, just collapse the group.